# what can be done by a telegram chat ID?

Tags: telegram, telegram-bot, python-telegram-bot, telepot

if someone find my telegram chat ID (instead of my phone number or username), what can do with that?

is it dangerous?!

is it a big deal that someone can find my ID? should I worry about it?

Comment: I think only bots can send messages using the chat ID but first you need authorize the bot so it can sends messages to you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If someone with a (user)bot wants to send you a message, they can do that via the userID only. But only if they have "seen" you. Seeing you is considering their client to receive a message from you, be it in a private message or group.

Bots can only send you a message if you have started it in a private chat, otherwise they can only send you a message in a group they share with you.

So there is no real risk of people knowing your ID.